# GETTING -> "3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument" Using GG TEXT TO SPEECH

Tags: google

I'm getting this error : "3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argumen" using GG text to speech with SSML text.

Do you have any idea ?

Thank you